# How to select a only a paticular P tag inside div tag hierarchically

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to select the only 2nd `<p>` of 2nd `<div>`tag?

Is there any hierarchy we can associate in CSS tags ?

Below is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
p:nth-of-type(2) {
background: #ff0000;
}    
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the widest browser support you can use `+` selector combined with `:first-child`.

```
div + div p:first-child + p {color: red;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vkm2zuaq/

OR using `:nth-child`:

```
div:nth-child(2) p:nth-child(2) {color: red;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vkm2zuaq/1/

Answer (score 0):

`nth-child` will do the job, try following code

```
div:nth-child(2) p:nth-child(2){
   /*---- css code-------*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    div:nth-child(2) p:nth-child(2){
       color:red;
    }
```

also check out this Post by Chris Coyer - it covers all answers to this topic:

[CSS Tricks - how nth work](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)